# What is the real result of an sklearn analysis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to get the result of a sklearn analysis, not the accuracy. I mean, I want to see the what my model is resulting.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

# train the classifier using the training data
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

acc_test = clf.score(features_test, labels_test)
acc_train = clf.score(features_train, labels_train)

print ("Train Accuracy:", acc_train)
```

All i have here is the accuracy, I tried so far(i found this solution on stack, perhaps I've missed something), but it is not working:

```
labels = clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
print (labels.dtype)
```

I have two possible outputs (0 or 1), and then I want to see by my self the proper results, a **csv file**. How could I do that?

Comment: You are looking for `.predict` ... Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

`clf.fit` returns self. So you are not getting the labels back, but an instance of the classifier.

This should predict the values of the test data. You can save it into a csv file if you want for your ease.

```
preds_test = clf.predict(features_test)
print(preds_test)
```

Comment: Thanks!! My test size is set to 0.20. If I want to get the whole data, I should choose test size to 1? Even it doesnt looks trusty? Or is it better to save the model, and then apply to the whole data? Thanks!!

Comment: Your prediction of the classifier should be evaluated on the Test set, which has not been seen by the classifier. If you want to see the whole dataset, you can feed it before you split it.